# Sql command confusion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vbscript

Need some SQL advice please

I am using a program called WinCC, in which I am using Vb script language with SQL.

I have a SQL table in which there are 3 columns, TagName, Value and Date

I need to display the Value for each TagName for each day in the chosen month.

The below SQL query give me same value for each day in the month. When I have different values for each day in the month.

```
Tags(0) = "Tag1"
Tags(1) = "Tag2"

TempTags(0) = "Temp1"
TempTags(1) = "Temp2"

  ConnectionString = "Provider=SQL Native Client;Server=WIN81   \WINCC;Database=Teams;Trusted_Connection=yes"        

 Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set rs = CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")     
 Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
 Connection.Open  

For i = 0 To 2

    SQLStr = "select Value FROM atrperformancestats WHERE TagName =   '"+Tags(i)+"'And Month(Date)='"+date+"'"   
     rs = Connection.Execute(SQLStr)   
     HMIRuntime.Tags(TempTags(i)).Write rs("Value")             

Next
```

I have tried changing my SQL query to get the value for each day in the user selected month but I am failing miserably...please help

Thank you so much

Comment: That is not VB.NET code, so the first thing to clear up is what you are using

Comment: @Plutonix the OP clearly said VBScript

Comment: I am using a program called WinCC made by Siemens, in which I am using Vb script language with SQL.....

Comment: @xirokx the SQL *very explicitly* only looks at the month of the date, so yes: we should *expect* it to return the same for every day in the month. Look at the `...Month(Date)='"+date+"'...`, specifically. Also: *parameterize*. Always, always parameterize. ADODB supports parameters just fine. What did you *intend* the SQL to do differently?

Comment: I need to change my sql query to display the value for each day in the month. I am using ...Month(Date)='"+date+"'..., because in the user interface, there is a datepicker, so I am selecting the month only and not the whole date.   I dont know how to go through each day in the month , any ideas?

Comment: @xirokx firstly, note that if you only compare the month, the *year* isn't held to account. At the moment you'll get a row per record; it isn't clear to me what you want to do here... are you looking to aggregate? or...?

Comment: Forgetting the above code for a sec. I have 1 SQL table with 3 columns, TagName, Value and Date. I have U.I.  with a datepicker and 31 empty boxes.  If user selects month - July, all 31 boxes should receive a value read from DB. So i need SQL query for this.

Comment: `Date` is a built-in function that returns today's date. Maybe try calling your date variable something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns multiple rows, you need a `While` loop to process the result set.  Below is a parameterized example that assumes `date` is an integer representing the month.

```
Const adVarChar = 200
Const adInteger = 3
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adCmdText = 1

Tags(0) = "Tag1"
Tags(1) = "Tag2"

TempTags(0) = "Temp1"
TempTags(1) = "Temp2"

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQL Native Client;Server=WIN81   \WINCC;Database=Teams;Trusted_Connection=yes"        

Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
Connection.Open  

Command.ActiveConnection = Connection
Command.CommandType = adCmdText

Command.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM atrperformancestats WHERE TagName = ? And Month(Date) = ?;"   

Set parmTagName = command.CreateParameter("TagName", adVarchar, adParamInput, 100)
Command.Parameters.Append(parmTagName)
Set parmDate = command.CreateParameter("Date", adInteger, adParamInput)
command.Parameters.Append(parmDate)

For i = 0 To 1

    parmTagName.Value = Tags(i)
    parmDate.Value = date
    Set rs = Command.Execute()
    While rs.EOF = False
        HMIRuntime.Tags(TempTags(i)).Write rs("Value").Value             
        rs.MoveNext
    WEnd

    rs.Close

Next
```

Comment: thanks for the code but It does not work. The program I am using WinCC does not give me error messages unless I use "Msgbox" its not an I.D.E as it where...I tried all the code you gave and then just the while loop but still did not work...Can we not just amend my SQL query or add a while loop to it?

Comment: I did test this code using Windows Scripting Host and it works as expected, except I had to use WScript.Echo instead of the HMIRuntime object to display the output.  I'm not familiar with WinCC but I expect could incorporate the While loop in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

In WinCC , a SCADA program which is not very code savy I eventually found a way...

```
        j = 0
        SQLStr = "Select Value FROM table1 WHERE Name =  '" + Names(i) + "' And Month(Date) = '" + MonthSelect + "' order by date asc"                      
        rs.Open SQLStr, Connection                          
        Do Until j = 31                         
            HMIRuntime.Tags(arrayInt(i)).Write rs("Value")              
            rs.MoveNext     
            i = i +1
            j = j +1
        Loop
```

And it works !!!

Thanks for all the help , your recommendation of a loop got me thinking